# how to get the shortest distance or path across several points in the map

Tags: path, distance, point, shortest

In the map, there are many points(paths), but I want to only visit some interesting points. I want to find the shortest distance or path which included my interesting points. But without considering going back to starting point.

I find the Dijkstra's algorithm or Floyd algorithm can not get it. How to get ? help!
which algorithm? or Matlab python code is OK.

which algorithm? or Matlab python code is OK.